# LightInject Determine type being resolved?

Tags: light-inject

I am looking at moving from Ninject to a lighter weight (and faster) Ioc framework.

I picked up LightInject and am having a play, but can't find how to do the following:

From within a call to RegisterConstructorDependency I want to be able to determine the type of the object being resolved. The Param info gives me everything I need to know about the parameter location. But I cannot determine the target of the injection.

This is problematic when attempting to inject string values into constructors.

An example:

```
public interface IService { void Go(); }

public class Impl1 : IService { 

  public Impl1(string needsA){ }

  public void Go(){ }

}

public class Impl2 : IService {

   public Impl1(string needsA, string needsB){ }

  public void Go(){ }

}

// Elsewhere
container.Register<IService, Impl1>();
container.Register<IService, Impl2>();
container.RegisterConstructorDependency<string>((factory, paramInfo) => ??? );
```

How in the registration of the constructor arg can I determine which implementation (Impl1 or Impl2) is being resolved. They may need different values to be passed to 'needsA'.

It may be that LightInject can't provide this information, and I need to expand my search.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of LightInject. You can get to the type being resolved via the paramInfo.Member.DeclaringType